# How to upload large file(s) in SharePoint?

Tags: file-upload

The code that I am using which successfully uploads large file(s) to on- premises SharePoint 2013 (I have uploaded 1.9 GB file using this code) is given below. This was run successfully in some computers but failed in others. The configuration in on of the computers where this code failed is Windows XP SP3 32 bit with 4GB RAM. The 1.9 GB file is not getting uploaded through browser also. I am using Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

```
m_ClientContext.RequestTimeout = Timeout.Infinite;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(m_SourceFilePath.Text, FileMode.Open))
{
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(m_ClientContext, szFullFilePath, fs, true);
}
```

I know a part of the solution, i.e., to upload it in chunks. I have read much about this. But I am not getting a proper solution. Its been more than a week I am trying different tricks to solve this. Kindly help me in solving this problem.

Edit: The same file which I have uploaded to SharePoint 2013 in Windows Server 2008 R2 programmatically some days ago is not getting uploaded to it now. It fails to get uploaded to SharePoint 2013 through browser also in Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Have you checked maxRequestLength? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288682/iis-7-httpruntime-maxrequestlength-limit-of-2097151

Comment: @JamesLove : Yes, I have already done that.

Comment: I'd place my bet your SQL Server is not properly [configurated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh292622.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your 2010 server has increased its max upload limmit! currently the default is 50mb not 2GB.

- [Configure the maximum upload file size.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424404(office.14).aspx#Section3c)

sounds like 2013 machine was ammended to accept larger file uploads!

to change it:

- goto **central admin** -> **application managment** -> **manage web applications**
- click on the web app that you want to increase upload size
- click on **general settings drop down** -> **general settings** -> scroll down in the popup untill you see "**Maximum Upload Size**" -> set to a reasonable ammount like 2250Mb for 2.2GB

forgot to mention that you need to reflect the changes within the web.config aswell!

```
httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" maxRequestLength="225000"
```

it could be that your timing out for some reason on some older legacy computers compared to others which are maybe newer?!

you could also change the chunk file size:

> To set the large file chunk size to 1,073,741,824 bytes (1024 MB), use
>   the following syntax:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn large-file-chunk-size -pv 1073741824
```

> To view the current setting of the large file chunk size property, use
>   the following syntax:

```
stsadm -o getproperty -pn large-file-chunk-size –url http://server_name
```

above requires iisreset!

- [Large-file-chunk-size: Stsadm property (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262061(v=office.12).aspx)

what error are you getting in your uls logs? is it even getting to that point?

Comment: Its not 2010.I have already done the first two steps that you have typed here. I don't know how to set stsadm in SharePoint 2013. Both the links that you pointed out doesn't apply to SharePoint 2013.

Comment: sorry for some reason i thought it was 2010, just read your question and it does state 2013! lol manic fridays! what browser version are you using?

Comment: Its the latest chrome and latest mozilla beta version. But I have to programmatically upload the document to SharePoint.