# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request While uploading file(40MB) using CSOM (C#)

Tags: 2010, document-library, csom, large-file

I am trying to upload a file with size 40MB in Document Library using SharePoint 2010 Managed CSOM (C#).

I am using following code

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
myCache.Add(new Uri(siteUrl), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential(userName, password));
clientContext.Credentials = myCache;
List documentLibrary = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibraryName);
clientContext.Load(documentLibrary);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 

byte[] bFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
FileCreationInformation file = new FileCreationInformation();
file.Content = bFile;
file.Url = url;
file.Overwrite = true;
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File newFile = documentLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add(file);
clientContext.Load(newFile);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I am using SharePoint.Client.dll of **version 14.0.0.0** so can't use methods provided for SP2013.

When I try to upload my file it throws me following exception

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder
>   sb)    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()    at
>   TestSampleApp.Program.uploadLargeData() in
>   d:\RND\TestSampleApp\TestSampleApp\Program.cs:line 47    at
>   TestSampleApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   d:\RND\TestSampleApp\TestSampleApp\Program.cs:line 16    at
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
>   args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

I have gone through

- [How to upload large file(s) in SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84506/how-to-upload-large-files-in-sharepoint)
- [Issues Uploading Large Files To SharePoint](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenh/2012/11/15/issues-uploading-large-files-to-sharepoint/)
- [SharePoint 2010: HowTo upload a file of the size of 1 GB using
  client object model](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2529243)

All the setting specified in this links are already implemented. But still the error is being thrown.

Initially I was not able to upload the file using GUI too. But after making changes I am now able to upload 40MB file through UI. But not from CSOM (C#) code.

Please provide suggestion what I should configure additionally to get it resolved.

**Edits**

I also want to update the document property at the time of upload. Currently I am doing this with following code:

```
newFile.ListItemAllFields[internalNames-1] = values-1;
newFile.ListItemAllFields[internalNames-2] = values-2;
newFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Is this possible with `SaveBinaryDirect()` in the same call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should be using some other method that bypasses the executQuery. I think its got a set timeout and max 2mb file limit.

use `SaveBinaryDirect` with `filestream`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.savebinarydirect(v=office.14)

example function to call:

```
public void SaveBinaryDirect(ClientContext ctx, string libraryName, string filePath)
        {
            Web web = ctx.Web;
            // Ensure that the target library exists. Create it if it is missing.
            if (!LibraryExists(ctx, web, libraryName))
            {
                CreateLibrary(ctx, web, libraryName);
            }

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, string.Format("/{0}/{1}", libraryName, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath)), fs, true);
            }

        }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

Follow these links and it will serve your purpose.

https://sharepointlessons.wordpress.com/2015/01/26/upload-large-files-using-csom-and-memory-streams/

http://www.stuartroberts.net/index.php/2014/05/09/sending-large-data-csom/

Comment: Your second link leads to some positive solution. I am working on it. But Please include some of essential part of the code into your answer other wise it will be of no use if link get broken.